# How to get record based on Exec Date and Exec Time column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hp-alm

I would like to get the latest record based on Exec Date and Exec Time columns.

Type of Exec Date column is datetime. Type of Exec Time column is varchar.

However, as it is not on the same column, I'm not able to do the filter.

Is it possible to do it with SQL?

**Example**

*Data*

```
RN_TEST_ID  | RN_RUN_ID  | RN_EXECUTION_DATE   | RN_EXECUTION_TIME | ST_STATUS
585858      | 214566     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  16:30:12         | P
585858      | 214566     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  16:30:12         | N
585858      | 214566     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  16:30:12         | N
585858      | 214566     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  16:30:12         | P
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | P
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | P
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | F
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | F
124578      | 852369     | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 |  12:20:01         | P
124578      | 852369     | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 |  12:20:01         | P
124578      | 852369     | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 |  12:20:01         | P
124578      | 852369     | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 |  12:20:01         | P
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | N
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
```

*Expected Result*

```
RN_TEST_ID  | RN_RUN_ID  | RN_EXECUTION_DATE   | RN_EXECUTION_TIME | ST_STATUS
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | P
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | P
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | F
585858      | 963247     | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 |  17:51:15         | F
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | N
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
124578      | 148623     | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 |  10:51:48         | F
```

Can you please help me to get this result?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

As I can't use CTE as I'm doing queries into HPALM, I tried to use a sub-request.

```
SELECT RN_TEST_ID, RN_RUN_ID, RN_EXECUTION_DATE, RN_EXECUTION_TIME, ST_STATUS
FROM (
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RN_TEST_ID ORDER BY RN_EXECUTION_DATE, RN_EXECUTION_TIME) AS DR, RUN.*
FROM RUN
) AS REQ
INNER JOIN STEP ON REQ.RN_RUN_ID = STEP.ST_RUN_ID
WHERE DR = 1 AND REQ.RN_ASSIGN_RCYC = '1100'.
```

However, I'm geeting all records instead of getting the most recent records per TEST_ID (based on Exec Date and Exec Time) and I don't understand why ...

Can you please help me?

Comment: What data types are the date and time columns

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Type of Exec Date column is datetime. Type of Exec Time column is varchar.

Comment: Why on earth have a Date*time* column and only store a date, and a varchar column instead of a *time* column for a time? Datetime caters for both, clue is in the name :0)

Comment: I dont know ... But I dont have the choice. I have to use existing database ...

Comment: @Stu The design is not optimal, but assuming date and time be stored as text but in a sortable ISO format, it can still be used.  In fact, on some databases such as SQLite which do not have formal date types, this is the only option.

Comment: Where does `TEST_ID` appear in your data set?

Comment: I updated dataset based on sql query I posted.

Comment: Why do you want to get the _latest_ records for `585858` but the _earliest_ for `124578` ?  Why are there only _three_ records for `124578` ?

Comment: This is latest for both. For `124578`  date is not the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen regarding the 3 records, it is a copy paste error. I updated the table. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing in my answer has changed other than the renaming of some columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RN_TEST_ID
                           ORDER BY RN_EXECUTION_DATE DESC, RN_EXECUTION_TIME DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT RN_TEST_ID, RN_RUN_ID, RN_EXECUTION_DATE, RN_EXECUTION_TIME, ST_STATUS
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that it is usually preferable to store date and time as a single datetime/timestamp column.  You may wish to change your design at some point.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. However, I cannot change the database ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposal. I updated the question with additional informations as I cant use `CTE`

Comment: If you don't want to use a CTE, then just use a subquery.  I have answered the question based on the data you did include above.

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot to mentioned it in the question.